# Woocommerce - Display payment method "payment on delivery" only for Admin Users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, meta-boxes

Please,

how can i set on Woocommerce the payment method **"payment on delivery"** only for **Admin Profile User**?

Is that possible?

This means, the payment method **"payment on delivery"** will be available on the **checkout page** only for users logged on WP and with admin profile.

Gratitude for the help!

Answer (score 1):

yes with `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` and one condition `is_user_admin()`

Example

```
// define the woocommerce_available_payment_gateways callback 
function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) { 
    $delete = false;
    foreach ($available_gateways as $key => $gateway) {
        if($gateway === [[[[payment on delivery]]]] && !is_user_admin()){
            unset($available_gateways[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hello @Sco , Thank you so much for the huge Help. Beautiful!!!!!! i'll do the test and i comeback to give you the honor! Gratitude

Comment: Hello @sco,
I was reading the documentation trying to find out the code that i must use here:
`[[[[payment on delivery]]]]`
Doc: [link](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-gateways-cod-class-wc-gateway-cod.html#source-view.58)

and i tried so:

`if($gateway === ['Cash on delivery'] && !is_user_admin()){`  
or this  
`if($gateway === ['cod'] && !is_user_admin()){`

But nothing still happens. **Cash on delivery** is still on the checkout page available. What String or Variable should i use please?

Comment: Based on the script below...that's was what i tried to use:  

/**
* Setup general properties for the gateway.
*/
```protected function setup_properties() {

 $this->id                 = 'cod';
 $this->icon               = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cod_icon', '' );
 $this->method_title       = __( 'Cash on delivery', 'woocommerce' );
 $this->method_description = __( 'Have your customers pay with cash (or by other means) upon delivery.', 'woocommerce' );
 $this->has_fields         = false;

}
```

Comment: Hello @sco, unfortunately, this solution for me it's not working. i need to post another question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by adjusting Sco's code to the following:

```
    // remove certain payment options if not logged in as staff
    public function checkout_limit_payment_methods($available_gateways){
    $delete = false;
    foreach ($available_gateways as $key => $gateway) {
        if($key === "bacs" || $key === "cheque" && !is_user_admin()){
                    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                        $user = wp_get_current_user();
                        $allowed_roles = array( 'shop_manager', 'editor', 'administrator', 'author' );
                        if ( !array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
                        // delete payment methods for any user without roles in array
                unset($available_gateways[$key]);
                        }
                    } else {
                    // delete payment methods for any user not logged in
            unset($available_gateways[$key]);
            }
                }
    }
    return $available_gateways; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function custom_enable_cod_for_shop_manager( $available_gateways ) {

// Check if the user is a shop_manager
$user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

    // Enable Cash on Delivery for shop_manager
    $available_gateways['cod'] = new WC_Gateway_COD();
}

return $available_gateways;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'custom_enable_cod_for_shop_manager' );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).